# How to make a width binding in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple elements in different divs, that should be aligned at some line. 
I can hardcode its width (40% for example), but it seems to be ugly. I also can use JS on page load to specify exact values in pixels (but it won't work for resizing very well).

How can I avoid this zigzag?[image]

Here is desired result (but I have to hardcode `width: 30%` to make it work):
[image]

markup:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_patchSize</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_patchSize" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.PatchSize" initial-value="@Model.Custom.PatchSize" value="@Model.Custom.PatchSize.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.PatchSize)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_scanInterval</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_scanInterval" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.ScanInterval" initial-value="@Model.Custom.ScanInterval" value="@Model.Custom.ScanInterval.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.ScanInterval)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_maxWaitingTime</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_maxWaitingTime" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MaxWaitingTime" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MaxWaitingTime" value="@Model.Custom.MaxWaitingTime.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MaxWaitingTime)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_shutdownTimeout</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_shutdownTimeout" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.ShutdownTimeout" initial-value="@Model.Custom.ShutdownTimeout" value="@Model.Custom.ShutdownTimeout.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.ShutdownTimeout)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_maximumBytes</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_maximumBytes" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitMs</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitMs" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitCount</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitCount" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML <table> or CSS table maybe useful for that.

Comment: display:table-cell; is the way to go

Comment: @Alex Zhukovskiy Are you willing to use **JQuery**?

Comment: @Pangloss unfortunly, I should use boostrap's input-group (becuase other controls are builded in same manner, so I should persist UX), and my CSS knowlege is not good enough to emulate it myself with a table.

Comment: @divy3993 I wrote my thoughts about JS (which is also means jQuery with 99% probability), I want to avoid it if possible, but if it's the only way to achieve it then I have no choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as adding the following CSS rule:

```
.input-group {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Example:

```css
.panel-body {
    border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
.panel-body:before,
.panel-body:after {
    display: none !important;
}
.input-group {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_patchSize</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_patchSize" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.PatchSize" initial-value="@Model.Custom.PatchSize" value="@Model.Custom.PatchSize.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.PatchSize)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_scanInterval</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_scanInterval" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.ScanInterval" initial-value="@Model.Custom.ScanInterval" value="@Model.Custom.ScanInterval.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.ScanInterval)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_maxWaitingTime</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_maxWaitingTime" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MaxWaitingTime" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MaxWaitingTime" value="@Model.Custom.MaxWaitingTime.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MaxWaitingTime)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_shutdownTimeout</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_shutdownTimeout" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.ShutdownTimeout" initial-value="@Model.Custom.ShutdownTimeout" value="@Model.Custom.ShutdownTimeout.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.ShutdownTimeout)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_maximumBytes</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_maximumBytes" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitMs</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitMs" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitCount</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitCount" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, Bootstrap adds pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` on `.panel-body`, which result in extra space when `border-spacing` is used. Simply hiding them seems to fix the problem.

Also any `!important` in the example above was only necessary for the example to work here. If you include your stylesheet after Bootstrap's, they are not needed.

Comment: Hmm, it's very good, but now I lost all margins. Can I get them back? When I use `border-spacing` margins appears, but I need only margins between rows, while it adds margins between every element in "table".

Comment: Hmm, you are very good in CSS :) Thank you for an answer. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the properties of a table to get the effect you want. This solution can also be modified to work well with a responsive design.

```css
div.table{
  display: table;
}
div.table div.tr{
  display: table-row;
}
div.table div.tr div.td{
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
div.table div.tr div.td div.label{
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
div.table div.tr div.td div.value{
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="tr">
  <div class="td">
   <div class="label">sourceObserver_patchSize</div>
  </div>
  <div class="td">
   <div class="value">value</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tr">
  <div class="td">
   <div class="label">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="td">
   <div class="value">...</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve such result by setting monotype font, `white-space: pre` and padding `span` elements with spaces to the longest one

example:

```
<style>
    .input-group-addon {
        white-space: pre;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    }
</style>

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_patchSize          </span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_patchSize" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.PatchSize" initial-value="@Model.Custom.PatchSize" value="@Model.Custom.PatchSize.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.PatchSize)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_scanInterval       </span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_scanInterval" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.ScanInterval" initial-value="@Model.Custom.ScanInterval" value="@Model.Custom.ScanInterval.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.ScanInterval)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_maxWaitingTime     </span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_maxWaitingTime" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MaxWaitingTime" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MaxWaitingTime" value="@Model.Custom.MaxWaitingTime.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MaxWaitingTime)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_shutdownTimeout    </span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_shutdownTimeout" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.ShutdownTimeout" initial-value="@Model.Custom.ShutdownTimeout" value="@Model.Custom.ShutdownTimeout.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.ShutdownTimeout)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_maximumBytes       </span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_maximumBytes" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.MaximumBytes)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitMs   </span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitMs" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitMs)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group margin-bottom">
        <span class="input-group-addon input-source-observer">sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitCount</span>
        <input id="sourceObserver_freeMemoryWaitCount" type="text" data-parsley-type="integer" min="1" max="1000000" class="form-control" data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="@Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount" initial-value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount" value="@Model.Custom.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount.RenderIfNotEqual(Model.Default.MemoryLimit.FreeMemoryWaitCount)">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="restoreInput(event)" value="Восстановить" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="clearInput(event)" value="Очистить" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```